# Error in R file after using "=" as an id for a TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file

When I was working on my layout file, I named by accident a TextView with '='.
I renamed the widget with another valid id but after a build, I have an error in my R.java file :

```
 public static final class id {
        public static final int ==0x7f0b0086;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you probably edited the wrong file. Check it again

Comment: clean and rebuild project

Comment: I looked in my layout files, I didnt find any widget with that name.

Comment: I did a rebuild and clean but no changes

Comment: can you share your layout file ?

Comment: Here a link to the two files that I have one is a landscape file :
[link](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AJxoyT6788RfpS8&id=E6B14AE690DD4222%21888&cid=E6B14AE690DD4222)

Comment: @Rida try with my answer and let me know if problem resolved or not.

Comment: In fact I tryed it but it didn't work, I tried a radical solution by recreating the activity and it did work for me.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Clean` and `Rebuild` your project.

or

Close your project and restart android studio.

or

if problem not solved then on the main menu select `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart`